# Scrabble Word Scorer

Tags: python, string

I need to write a program where it asks for a single word which will be in lowercase and output what the value of that word would be in scrabble. 
Eg:

```
Enter word: quiz
22
```

To tell the truth, i really don't have any idea of how to do this question and what i have done so far is probably wrong. I have only started coding 2 weeks ago so i am not sure about many of the commands such as how to split a word into separate character. For far my program is:

```
SCORES = {
  'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3 , 'd' : 2, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 2,
  'h' : 4, 'i' : 1, 'j' : 8 , 'k' : 5, 'l' : 1, 'm' : 3, 'n' : 1,
  'o' : 1, 'p' : 3, 'q' : 10, 'r' : 1, 's' : 1, 't' : 1, 'u' : 1,
  'v' : 4, 'w' : 4, 'x' : 8 , 'y' : 4, 'z' : 10,
}
a=input('Enter word: ')
b=a.split()
for b in SCORES:
  c=SCORES[b]
```

Could anyone please help me in getting an idea of how to do this and telling me any commands that i might need for this question.

Comment: You need to spend some Time with the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) in the documentation.  [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) is also pretty good.  Practice, practice, practice the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you started well already by defining the SCORES dictionary.

Now your can translate your word into a list of values by:

```
myword = raw_input("Enter word: ")
letter_values = map(lambda letter: SCORES[letter], myword)
```

Then you can just sum it up to get the total score:

```
word_value = sum(letter_values)
print(word_value)
```

the map function applies a function elementwise on the string and the lambda just defines an in-line functions which picks the score for each letter.

Comment: You can use `SCORES.__getitem__` directly instead of the lambda

Comment: Or alternatively use a plain `for char in word` loop and add up the character values in another variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your explanation of the commands.